# How to prevent the xmlns="" namespace declaration in copy-of Tags?

Tags: xml, xslt, openxml, xslt-2.0

I am trying to create an OOXML document with XSL. Therefore I need the following namespace declaration in the root Tag "Workbook" ,otherwise Excel will not accept the XML document as an OOXML.

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

XSL Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="CONTENT">
            <Worksheet ss:Name="1st Sheet">
                <Row>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Cell Text 2</Data>
                </Row>
            </Worksheet>
            <Worksheet ss:Name="2st Sheet">
                <Row>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Cell Text 2</Data>
                </Row>
            </Worksheet>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- create output -->
        <Workbook>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$CONTENT" copy-namespaces="no"/>
        </Workbook>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
          xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
   <Worksheet xmlns="" ss:Name="1st Sheet">
      <Row>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Cell Text 2</Data>
      </Row>
   </Worksheet>
   <Worksheet xmlns="" ss:Name="2st Sheet">
      <Row>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Cell Text 2</Data>
      </Row>
   </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

The first Tag Worksheet from *xsl:copy-of* from the variable contains an empty **xmlns=""** declaration. Currently I have no idea. I tryed to use the *xsl:copy-of* inside a *xsl:template*, but same result. Also if I do the declaration not in the *xsl:stylesheet* element, but in the Workbook Tag - same result.

Maybe someone have a proposal or idea. Will be great.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what the problem is. Clearly in your variable you set `<Worksheet xmlns=""`, so why are you doing that if you don't want to have `<Worksheet xmlns=""` in the output? The `copy-namespaces="no"` does never change the namespace of a node, it only helps preventing the copy of in scope namespaces.

Comment: Why do you say you need to declare the XSLT namespace on a `Workbook` element? You mean the spreadsheet namespace, right? Be careful with declaring a default namespace in an XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Excel expect the decalaration of `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` in the first Tag `<Worksheet>`, because otherwise Excel is creating one worksheet with whole the XML document as a text.

Comment: @Martin: If I have the Worksheet Tags with the empty declaration `<Worksheet xmlns="">`, I get an error from Excel: Cannot read the file. Wihtout the empty declaration in the `<Worksheet>` Tag and manually added declaration in Workbook it works fine.

Comment: @Martin: You are right I did it in the XSL. Copy-and-Past issue. Shit. Sorry, but without in the XSL i get the same result. Corrected in the positng. My fault at the posting, because I rebuild it in a smaller example for these post.

Comment: Surely a `xmlns=""` in `Worksheet` would result in an invalid format, but besides that, your result even without the `xmlns` does not validate with the [Excel SpreadSheet schema](http://rep.oio.dk/microsoft.com/officeschemas/xsds/SpreadsheetML%20Schemas/excelss.xsd). `Row` elements must be contained in `Table` elements (which are missing from your file), and `Data` elements should be inside `Cell` elements (also missing). See [these examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats). You will have to fix those problems as well.

Comment: @helderdarocha:Yes the Table Tag is not inside the small example here, because in my normal huge result I have only a issue with `xmlns=""`! Thanks for the XSD, but the XSD schema is producing also errors with the normal file created by Excel.

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using to do the transformation? When I try your XSLT over at http://xsltransform.net/ it does not show the `xmlns=""`